# Cant access Wordpress dashboard it just re-directs to main page why?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

Im really worried Ive been editting my blog them all day fine but now I cant access the dashboard at all if I go to /wp-admin/ it puts a re-direct like this one below back to my home page;
http://www.louisemccomiskey.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.louisemccomiskey.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2Ftheme-editor.php&reauth=1.

The last thing I did on the dashboard was edit the settings where wordpress domain was located and then if you wanted the homepage to be in a separate place.
These settings were:
http://www.louisemccomiskey.com/blog/
and I changed one to:
http://www.louisemccomiskey.com/

I think think is the issue but I have no way of changing it back as it wont let me in,
any help would be much appreciated as Im slightly freaking out?
Thankyou
Louise

Comment: Do you have access to your wordpress database? If so, is phpMyAdmin or something similar installed?

Comment: Hi yes my database is hosted at dreamhost.com and i Think i have access to phpmyadmin, il check now! Why will this help?

Comment: Louise McComiskey: If/when you get access to phpMyAdmin, you can undo the change you made by selecting your `wp_options` table and running a query like `select * from wp_options where option_name = 'siteurl';` and editing the returned record.

Comment: Thankyou so much this worked perfectly panic over!!

Comment: Glad it worked; I've added that as the answer so this question can be removed from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo the change you made by selecting your `wp_options` table and running a query like `select * from wp_options where option_name = 'siteurl';` and editing the returned record.

Incidentally, if you'd like to have your homepage link elsewhere, you can use this plugin -- [Page Links To](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/) to achieve it.